# Hibernate query.list() returning single char value

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have a column in DB , which is of type char(20) and I mapped the column as below

```
  <property name="my_cloumn" type="string">
        <column name="My_column" sql-type="char(20)">
       </column>
  </property>
```

I have the data for this column in db like 123456789123456789

when I execute Query.list(), I am getting first char only i.e. '1'

what might be causing the issue?

I am using Hibernate 3.3

Update 1:

I am performing below before executing Query.list()

```
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a HBM bug there which isn't properly parsing the `char(20)` data-type consistently across the framework.  To be explicit, try this mapping instead:

```
<property name="my_cloumn" type="string">
    <column name="My_column" sql-type="char" length="20" />
</property>
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 10.1.3 DB

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL:

```
CAST(My_column AS VARCHAR2(20))
```

In Hibernate:

```
cast(my_cloumn as string)
```

> if ANSI cast() and extract() is supported by the underlying database

Which is true since you are using Oracle. I tried using CAST with CHAR(20) which does not fix the problem so you must use VARCHAR2. My situation was using Oracle SQL so I was not able to test the Hibernate example I gave but you get the idea.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions